# return sum(h_in_second, m_in_second, s_second) TypeError: sum expected at most 2 arguments, got 3

Tags: python, functional-programming

Why I can't return sum value in function ?

```
def second_since_midnight(h, m, s):
    
    h_in_second = 3600 * h
    m_in_second = m * 60
    s_second = s
    
    return sum(h_in_second, m_in_second, s_second)


print(second_since_midnight(13, 30, 45))
```

Kind regard

Comment: `sum()` wants a *single sequence* of values, not individual parameters.  Try `sum((h_in_second, m_in_second, s_second))`  (note the extra set of parentheses, turning the three values into a single tuple).

Comment: `sum([h_in_second, m_in_second, s_second])` perhaps? See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), sum takes two arguments: An iterable and a `start` parameter. You need to pass the values in as an iterable, as it is python thinks you're trying to pass `h_in_second` as the number to sum, `m_in_second` as the `start` number, and a mystery third argument

Answer (score 1):

Putting jasonharper's answer here since it seems to have solved the problem.

### You need to encase your values in an iterable, like a list or tuple

sum() takes a single sequence of values, not individual parameters.

Instead of `sum(h_in_second, m_in_second, s_second)` try encapsulating your values in a list like this `sum([h_in_second, m_in_second, s_second])`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) expects an iterable, rather than individual arguments to sum. *However* the error code your received says it takes "at most two arguments" which doesn't seem to mesh with this statement.

The second argument is the *start* value for the sum. As of Python 3.8 and later, this can be specified as a keyword argument.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> sum(a)
6
>>> sum(a, 1)
7
>>> sum(a, start=1)
7
```